# How to get values of all input fields which have the same name?

Tags: jsp

I am using JSP for my webpage. I used JavaScript to get a dynamic textbox and it works fine. But, my problem is how to take the values to next page as the dynamic textboxes have all the same name?

Comment: If it's JSP, tag it JSP, not Ruby on Rails. Come on.

Comment: You might want to add some code examples/samples to your question to make it easier for others to help.

Comment: You should also change the question's title to something descriptive. "Please help to solve this question" implicitly applies to all questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all input fields have the same name, use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) instead to grab the submitted values of all input fields with the same name. With [`getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) only the first one will be returned.

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("fieldname");
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, you'd like to do the form processing job in a Servlet class instead of a JSP file. To learn more about Servlets, check our [servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: hi balu thanks for your reply.Please suggest can i use sessions to get dynamic textbox values.As i am new to jsp please help to work on this.